# How to pass hash values into fields in registration form?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, gherkin

I am new to automation testing and have no experience in Ruby, nor any other programming language. However my current employer wants from me to start automating small tasks. The problem I stumbled upon is when trying to pass hash values into fields of a registration form.

This is my Gherkin Scenario:

[image]

On the left hand side of the when-statement is the name of the field in which I want to pass a certain value. The first two are input fields. The last hash "age" is a dropdown.

Can someone help me out by giving me an example ruby method, that would fill-in such a registration form, given the information above?

P.S.  The automation framework I use consists of Ruby, Cucumber and Watir Webdriver.

Comment: The answer will depend on the page HTML as well as if you are also using a page-object framework. In general, you would be iterating over each key-value pair to find a field and input the value. Example if the first column matched the element ids you could have `data.each_pair { |setting, value| browser.element(id: setting).to_subtype.set(value) }`. Though ideally you'd have a page-object framework which would get to something as simple as `page.populate_with(values)`.

Comment: please add some info about the web-page you're dealing with and if you're using page-object framework?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is untested, but something like this should work for you.

```
# Step definition
Given /^I enter the following credentials$/ do |table|
  # .drop(1) is to get rid of your first row with titles
  table.drop(1).each_pair do |setting, value|
    browser.element(name: setting).to_subtype.set(value) }
  end
end
```

Be carefull using Gherkin as a replacement for coding. It should be focussed on **what** you're trying to achieve, not **how** you're trying to achieve it.

I would recommend a scenario as follows:

```
Given RegularJohn is on the create account page
When he submits the create account form with his information
Then the successfully created message should display
```

Note that in your code you would need `RegularJohn` to be a configuration variable that is filled with the expected information information.

When you try to test a failure you could use a different variable, like `BadEmailAndy`. This way you keep it readable, maintainable and understandable.